# Manipulating list items with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am currently trying to manipulate a unordered list with jQuery, essentially I have a list of links in an unordered list, certain users only have access (all set server side) to certain files / pages.

I was hoping to use some jQuery to remove a few list items from the DOM, simply because it's more appealing to me to not have the user click on a link, load the page and then be displayed an error because they have insufficient access.

I already have an object setup, and have successfully removed one standalone link from the DOM, although I can't seem to get the selector right to remove the list items.

List HTML:

```
<div id="browse" class="bubble"> 
<blockquote>
<ul id="browses">
<li><a href="browse.php?id=15" class="browse">Access</a><br /></li> //trying to remove
<li><a href="browse.php?id=1" class="browse">Accounts</a><br /></li> //trying to remove
<li><a href="browse.php?id=2" class="browse">Browse's</a><br /></li> //trying to remove
<li><a href="browse.php?id=7" class="browse">Commands</a><br /></li> //trying to remove
<li><a href="browse.php?id=4" class="browse">Content</a><br /></li>
<li><a href="browse.php?id=8" class="browse">Logs</a><br /></li>
<li><a href="browse.php?id=10" class="browse">Sessions</a><br /></li>
<li><a href="browse.php?id=11" class="browse">Settings</a><br /></li> //trying to remove
<li><a href="browse.php?id=12" class="browse">Sites</a><br /></li> //trying to remove
</ul>   
</blockquote>
<cite>Browse and manage the currently active sites data</cite>
</div>
```

Object thus far:

```
Session = function(){
    this.init(phpdev_session);
}

$.extend(Session.prototype, {
    // object variables
    vars: '',

    init: function(phpdev_session){
        // do initialization here
        this.vars = phpdev_session;
    },

    restrict: function() {
        if (this.vars.account_class == '40') {
            //access client or less, remove manage another site link and a few browses from #browse ul
            //note: its all restricted server side, so its just a presentation layer.
            $('a#activate').remove();
            $('#browses').remove('li:eq(0)').remove('li:eq(1)').remove('li:eq(2)').remove('li:eq(3)').remove('li:eq(7)').remove('li:eq(8)');
        }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var session = new Session(phpdev_session);
    session.restrict();
});
```

Comment: Merely a suggestion, but NOT displaying a secured menu item versus displaying it, but having it appear "disabled", can often be a very non-intuitive UI design.  It's often easier to "see" what you don't have access to then the opposite (what you're design implies). :)

Comment: typo darnit: you're should be your :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think jQuery is the right tool for this (I would do it server-side), but I would add a class server-side to the items they don't have access to, then just do

```
$(".noAccess").remove();
```

If you're going to do that though, just remove them server-side since you'll have the code in place.

Comment: If this is going to be done on the JS side, `.restrictedAccess` might be more appropriate than `.noAccess` as it would be a hint that the action is "restricted." Otherwise, it will always be generated with "no access" regardless of whether or not the JS logic determines there is actually no access.

Comment: I am currently using smarty, which meant making new files, or editing existing tpl's with if statements (then assigning the vars to check against in all the files), All of which requiring more work than a few lines of jquery (and the server side validation was already there, just after the load).

Comment: I did give the class suggestion a go and it worked a treat, and all in  one file edit :) thanks